# jQuery animate height till max

Tags: jquery, css

What I need is some 'toggleDown' function for animate.
I know there is a `.slideDown()` but this just won't work the way I want.
I need the div to expand from the current height to the full height (full height=normal height ob the div)!

```
$("div#one").animate({height: "toggleDown"}, 100); // something like that
```

Thx in advance

Comment: How is the max height calculated?

Comment: it's the div-containers normal height

Comment: so, in other words, you want to calculate the height that the div would be if it didn't have a set height, then animate it to that height, then remove the set height. Are you using jQuery UI?

Comment: Why won't `slideDown` work? Are you looking maybe for `slideToggle`?

Comment: slidedown will slide from the 0 to open he does not want the 0 part

Comment: @Eric slideDown and slideUp only work with completely visible or completely hidden elements. It's animation will start from 0% or 100%

Comment: you need to know the height that you want to animate to, either get it from calculation or get it before the div shrinks then shrink it. so you have the number for later use. Basically, first grab the height from the full div, addclass to hide it or use jquery to hide it, either way, at this point you have the max height so you can use it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is not directly possible currently.* jQuery needs to know the final numeric height in order to be able to correctly animate an element w.r.t height. The `normal` or `auto` height as you mentioned is something that is determinable only after the DIV is rendered. At best, you can make an **invisible clone** (with `visibility: hidden`, NOT `display: none`) of your DIV, get its computed height and use that to animate your actual DIV.

Comment: "*At best, you can make an invisible close of your DIV, get its computed height and use that to animate your actual DIV.*" That is exactly what jQuery does for slideDown and slideUp. I wonder if there's an internal method they are using for that which could be re-used here.

Comment: @marius: Digging the source might reveal some clues. Its best to reuse that since it's pretty much guaranteed to be robust.